# DFS logic to traverse a graph

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I tried to literally convert recursive algorithm taught [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/) to iterative, by simulating the recursive stack exactly as much as possible.

I have tested my code and it passed all test cases.

Please let me know if any more improvements are possible.

Here is my code:

```
public class Graph
{
    private int tv; //total vertices
    private int te; //total edges

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjacencyList;

    public Graph(int tv)
    {
        this.tv = tv;

        adjacencyList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(tv);

        for (int i = 0; i < tv; i++)
        {
            adjacencyList.add(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
    }

    //adds edge for undirected graph
    //s - source, d - destination
    public void addEdge(int s, int d)
    {
        //need to check s & d are with in bounds

        adjacencyList.get(s).add(d);
        adjacencyList.get(d).add(s);

        te++;
    }

    public void dfsIterative()
    {
        boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[tv];

        for (int v = 0; v < tv; v++)
        {
            if (!isVisited[v])
            {
                dfsIterativeUtil(v, isVisited);
            }
        }
    }

    //sv - start vertex
    private void dfsIterativeUtil(int sv, boolean[] isVisited)
    {
        class Node
        {
            int v; //vertex in a graph
            int i; //current index of v's adjacency list

            Node(int v, int i)
            {
                this.v = v;
                this.i = i;
            }
        }

        Deque<Node> stack = new LinkedList<>();
        stack.push(new Node(sv, -1));

        while (!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            int cv = stack.peek().v; //cv - current vertex

            if (!isVisited[cv])
            {
                System.out.print(cv + " ");
                isVisited[cv] = true;
            }

            ArrayList<Integer> cvAdjList = adjacencyList.get(cv);

            int ci = ++stack.peek().i; //ci - current index in cvAdjList

            if (ci>=cvAdjList.size())
            {
                stack.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                int vtx = cvAdjList.get(ci);

                if (!isVisited[vtx])
                {
                    stack.push(new Node(vtx, -1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried few test cases and they passed. But I am unsure whether my algorithm is correct." Why? And what test cases did you try?

Comment: @Mast ,  test cases: 1) undirected graph, 2) directed graph, 3) completely disconnected graph, 4) graph with several disjoint sets, 5) graph with cycles, 6) graph with self loops and 7) edge cases.